# Should we have icons in Tags like SO?

Tags: discussion, tags

I spotted on SO that some of the tags have company icons embedded within them:

[image]

Should we not have similar ones for Esri, Mapinfo, Mapserver, etc?

If so:
- would we need permission from the vendors?
- who controls which ones have icons and which ones dont 'deserve' them.  (Has to have >200 occurrences?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are paid advertisements, which we are not currently pursuing on SE 2.0 sites outside of Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and sometimes Super User.

Comment: ahh. im with you.  Ud probably be able to get some cash from some of the major vendors like Esri if you did want to go down this line.  Thanks Jeff.

Comment: major cash from the big vendors ESRI, AUTODESK, TOMTOM, NOKIA, Apple, Mircosoft, Google.... who are in the GeoSpatial game now..